# Sencha Touch 2 local store and mysql database

Tags: sql, extjs, touch, store, local

I'm writing an app using Sencha Touch 2 and I want to use a local store to save data from a mysql database on my server. The app should work without internet too, so when I find a connection I have to sync the local database with my server database and I can't lose any data while the phone get the connection again.
On the local store I must be able to update records and then resend them to the server.
What type of store can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any type of store you need, what will make it local is its proxy. You can choose any [client side proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Client) that meets your requirements. For a simple single page application, a [memory proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory) may be enough. If you need long term storage and you can rely on HTML5, look at [`LocalStorage`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage) proxy, or even the [`Sql`](http://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/revisiting-the-sencha-touch-2-2-sql-proxy/) one.

Now, that only answers the part of your question about client-side storage. You will still have to find a solution for (1) loading data from the server into your client-side store, and (2) sending your local data to the server. As far as I know, Ext doesn't offers much support for this, so you'll have to hack it yourself.

Or you can try [this extension](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-offlinesyncstore) which seems to offer exactly what you need, that is setting two proxies on the same store, one for local storage, and one for exchanges with the server.